# Error_1_The name 'MainForm_ResizeMove' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#-3.0, directx, direct3d, directshow.net

I tried to recreate the BitmapMixer sample from [Directshow.NET](https://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/) in VS 2010 (The original sample works fine) and got the following errors in the Form1.cs

```
Error   1   The name 'MainForm_ResizeMove' does not exist in the current context    C:\Documents and Settings\TLNA\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\mybitmapMixer\myBitmapMixer\Form1.cs    177 13  myBitmapMixer
Error   2   The name 'MainForm_Paint' does not exist in the current context C:\Documents and Settings\TLNA\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\mybitmapMixer\myBitmapMixer\Form1.cs    289 49  myBitmapMixer
Error   3   The name 'MainForm_ResizeMove' does not exist in the current context    C:\Documents and Settings\TLNA\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\mybitmapMixer\myBitmapMixer\Form1.cs    290 45  myBitmapMixer
Error   4   The name 'MainForm_ResizeMove' does not exist in the current context    C:\Documents and Settings\TLNA\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\mybitmapMixer\myBitmapMixer\Form1.cs    291 43  myBitmapMixer
Error   5   The name 'SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged' does not exist in the current context    C:\Documents and Settings\TLNA\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\mybitmapMixer\myBitmapMixer\Form1.cs    292 69  myBitmapMixer
Error   6   The name 'MainForm_Paint' does not exist in the current context C:\Documents and Settings\TLNA\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\mybitmapMixer\myBitmapMixer\Form1.cs    300 49  myBitmapMixer
Error   7   The name 'MainForm_ResizeMove' does not exist in the current context    C:\Documents and Settings\TLNA\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\mybitmapMixer\myBitmapMixer\Form1.cs    301 45  myBitmapMixer
Error   8   The name 'MainForm_ResizeMove' does not exist in the current context    C:\Documents and Settings\TLNA\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\mybitmapMixer\myBitmapMixer\Form1.cs    302 43  myBitmapMixer
Error   9   The name 'SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged' does not exist in the current context    C:\Documents and Settings\TLNA\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\mybitmapMixer\myBitmapMixer\Form1.cs    303 69  myBitmapMixer
```

---

Here is the Form1.cs code :-

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using DirectShowLib;
using Microsoft.DirectX;
using Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace DirectShowLib.Sample
{
public partial class MainForm : Form
{


//private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;

private Color colorKey = Color.Violet; // The color use as ColorKey for GDI operations
private Bitmap colorKeyBitmap; // A RGB bitmap used for GDI operations.
private Bitmap alphaBitmap; // A ARGB bitmap used for Direct3D operations

// Managed Direct3D magic number to retrieve unmanaged Direct3D interfaces
private const int DxMagicNumber = -759872593;
private Device device = null; // A Managed Direct3D device
private PresentParameters presentParams;
private Surface surface = null; // A Direct3D suface filled with alphaBitmap
private IntPtr unmanagedSurface; // A pointer on the unmanaged surface

private IFilterGraph2 graphBuilder = null;
private IMediaControl mediaControl = null;
private IBaseFilter vmr9 = null;
private IVMRMixerBitmap9 mixerBitmap = null;
private IVMRWindowlessControl9 windowlessCtrl = null;
private bool handlersAdded = false; // Needed to remove delegates

// Menus stuff
private bool mixerEnabled = true;
private bool usingGDI = true;


public MainForm()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  // We paint the windows ourself
  this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

  // Get the colorkeyed bitmap without antialiasing
  colorKeyBitmap = BitmapGenerator.GenerateColorKeyBitmap(colorKey, false);
  // Get the bitmap with alpha transparency
  alphaBitmap = BitmapGenerator.GenerateAlphaBitmap();

  // Init Managed Direct3D
  InitializeDirect3D();
}



private void InitializeDirect3D()
{
  Device.IsUsingEventHandlers = false;

  // Basic Presentation Parameters...
  presentParams = new PresentParameters();
  presentParams.Windowed = true;
  presentParams.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;

  // Assume a hardware Direct3D device is available
  // Add MultiThreaded to be safe. Each DirectShow filter runs in a separate thread...
  device = new Device(
    0,
    DeviceType.Hardware,
    this,
    CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing | CreateFlags.MultiThreaded,
    presentParams
    );

  // Create a surface from our alpha bitmap
  surface = new Surface(device, alphaBitmap, Pool.SystemMemory);
  // Get the unmanaged pointer
  unmanagedSurface = surface.GetObjectByValue(DxMagicNumber);
}

private void CloseInterfaces()
{
  if (mediaControl != null)
    mediaControl.Stop();

  if (handlersAdded)
    RemoveHandlers();

  if (vmr9 != null)
  {
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(vmr9);
    vmr9 = null;
    windowlessCtrl = null;
    mixerBitmap = null;
  }

  if (graphBuilder != null)
  {
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(graphBuilder);
    graphBuilder = null;
    mediaControl = null;
  }

  menuMixer.Enabled = false;
}

private void BuildGraph(string fileName)
{
  int hr = 0;

  try
  {
    graphBuilder = (IFilterGraph2)new FilterGraph();
    mediaControl = (IMediaControl)graphBuilder;

    vmr9 = (IBaseFilter)new VideoMixingRenderer9();

    ConfigureVMR9InWindowlessMode();

    hr = graphBuilder.AddFilter(vmr9, "Video Mixing Renderer 9");
    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

    hr = graphBuilder.RenderFile(fileName, null);
    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

    mixerBitmap = (IVMRMixerBitmap9)vmr9;

    menuMixer.Enabled = true;
    mixerEnabled = true;
    usingGDI = false;
    UpdateMixerMenu();
    SetMixerSettings();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    CloseInterfaces();
    MessageBox.Show("An error occured during the graph building : \r\n\r\n" + e.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
  }
}

private void ConfigureVMR9InWindowlessMode()
{
  int hr = 0;

  IVMRFilterConfig9 filterConfig = (IVMRFilterConfig9)vmr9;

  // Not really needed for VMR9 but don't forget calling it with VMR7
  hr = filterConfig.SetNumberOfStreams(1);
  DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

  // Change VMR9 mode to Windowless
  hr = filterConfig.SetRenderingMode(VMR9Mode.Windowless);
  DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

  windowlessCtrl = (IVMRWindowlessControl9)vmr9;

  // Set "Parent" window
  hr = windowlessCtrl.SetVideoClippingWindow(this.Handle);
  DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

  // Set Aspect-Ratio
  hr = windowlessCtrl.SetAspectRatioMode(VMR9AspectRatioMode.LetterBox);
  DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

  // Add delegates for Windowless operations
  AddHandlers();

  // Call the resize handler to configure the output size
  MainForm_ResizeMove(null, null);
}

private void SetMixerSettings()
{
  int hr = 0;
  VMR9AlphaBitmap alphaBmp;

  if (!mixerEnabled) // Did the user disable the bitmap ?
  {
    // Get current Alpha Bitmap Parameters
    hr = mixerBitmap.GetAlphaBitmapParameters(out alphaBmp);
    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

    // Disable them
    alphaBmp.dwFlags = VMR9AlphaBitmapFlags.Disable;

    // Update the Alpha Bitmap Parameters
    hr = mixerBitmap.UpdateAlphaBitmapParameters(ref alphaBmp);
    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

    return;
  }

  if (usingGDI)
  {
    // Old school GDI stuff...
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(colorKeyBitmap);
    IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();
    IntPtr memDC = NativeMethodes.CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    IntPtr hBitmap = colorKeyBitmap.GetHbitmap();
    NativeMethodes.SelectObject(memDC, hBitmap);

    // Set Alpha Bitmap Parameters for using a GDI DC
    alphaBmp = new VMR9AlphaBitmap();
    alphaBmp.dwFlags = VMR9AlphaBitmapFlags.hDC | VMR9AlphaBitmapFlags.SrcColorKey | VMR9AlphaBitmapFlags.FilterMode;
    alphaBmp.hdc = memDC;
    alphaBmp.rSrc = new DsRect(0, 0, colorKeyBitmap.Size.Width, colorKeyBitmap.Size.Height);
    alphaBmp.rDest = GetDestRectangle();
    alphaBmp.clrSrcKey = ColorTranslator.ToWin32(colorKey);
    alphaBmp.dwFilterMode = VMRMixerPrefs.PointFiltering;
    alphaBmp.fAlpha = 0.75f;

    // Set Alpha Bitmap Parameters
    hr = mixerBitmap.SetAlphaBitmap(ref alphaBmp);
    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

    // Release GDI handles
    NativeMethodes.DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    NativeMethodes.DeleteDC(memDC);
    g.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
    g.Dispose();
  }
  else // Using a Direct3D surface
  {
    // Set Alpha Bitmap Parameters for using a Direct3D surface
    alphaBmp = new VMR9AlphaBitmap();
    alphaBmp.dwFlags = VMR9AlphaBitmapFlags.EntireDDS;
    alphaBmp.pDDS = unmanagedSurface;
    alphaBmp.rDest = GetDestRectangle();
    alphaBmp.fAlpha = 1.0f;
    // Note : Alpha values from the bitmap are cumulative with the fAlpha parameter.
    // Example : texel alpha = 128 (50%) & fAlpha = 0.5f (50%) = effective alpha : 64 (25%)

    // Set Alpha Bitmap Parameters
    hr = mixerBitmap.SetAlphaBitmap(ref alphaBmp);
    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
  }
}

private NormalizedRect GetDestRectangle()
{
  int hr = 0;
  int width, height, arW, arH;
  NormalizedRect rect = new NormalizedRect();

  hr = windowlessCtrl.GetNativeVideoSize(out width, out height, out arW, out arH);
  DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

  // Position the bitmap in the middle of the video stream.
  if (width >= height)
  {
    rect.top = 0.0f;
    rect.left = (1.0f - ((float)height / (float)width)) / 2;
    rect.bottom = 1.0f;
    rect.right = rect.left + (float)height / (float)width;
  }
  else
  {
    rect.top = (1.0f - ((float)width / (float)height)) / 2;
    rect.left = 0.0f;
    rect.right = rect.top + (float)width / (float)height;
    rect.bottom = 1.0f;
  }

  return rect;
}

private void UpdateMixerMenu()
{
  // Just manage the Mixer menu...
  menuMixerEnable.Checked = mixerEnabled;

  menuMixerGDI.Enabled = mixerEnabled;
  menuMixerGDI.Checked = usingGDI;
  menuMixerD3D.Enabled = mixerEnabled;
  menuMixerD3D.Checked = !usingGDI;
}

private void AddHandlers()
{
  // Add handlers for VMR purpose
  this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(MainForm_Paint); // for WM_PAINT
  this.Resize += new EventHandler(MainForm_ResizeMove); // for WM_SIZE
  this.Move += new EventHandler(MainForm_ResizeMove); // for WM_MOVE
  SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += new EventHandler(SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged); // for WM_DISPLAYCHANGE
  handlersAdded = true;
}

private void RemoveHandlers()
{
  // remove handlers when they are no more needed
  handlersAdded = false;
  this.Paint -= new PaintEventHandler(MainForm_Paint);
  this.Resize -= new EventHandler(MainForm_ResizeMove);
  this.Move -= new EventHandler(MainForm_ResizeMove);
  SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged -= new EventHandler(SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged);
}

private void RunGraph()
{
  if (mediaControl != null)
  {
    int hr = mediaControl.Run();
    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
  }
}

private void StopGraph()
{
  if (mediaControl != null)
  {
    int hr = mediaControl.Stop();
    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
  }
}

// Menus click handlers
private void menuFileOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    CloseInterfaces();
    BuildGraph(openFileDialog.FileName);
    RunGraph();
  }
}

private void menuFileClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  StopGraph();
  CloseInterfaces();
  this.Invalidate();
}

private void menuFileExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  StopGraph();
  CloseInterfaces();
  this.Dispose();
}

private void menuMixerEnable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  mixerEnabled = !mixerEnabled;
  UpdateMixerMenu();
  SetMixerSettings();
}

private void menuMixerGDI_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  usingGDI = true;
  UpdateMixerMenu();
  SetMixerSettings();
}

private void menuMixerD3D_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  usingGDI = false;
  UpdateMixerMenu();
  SetMixerSettings();
}

private void menuHelpAbout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string title = "About Bitmap mixer";
  string text = "DirectShow.Net VMR9 Bitmap mixer\r\nMake use of IVMRBitmapMixer9";

  AboutBox.Show(title, text);
}







}
}
```

---

Any help to resolve this is appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your form doesn't have the event handler functions declared and implemented.

When you do: 
`this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(MainForm_Paint);`
You are attaching an event handler using MainForm_Paint to the Paint event. 
So, when the paint event is fired every time your form needs to paint itself, the function MainForm_Paint should be fired as well.

You need to put in your form a definition for MainForm_Paint, for instance:

```
private void MainForm_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)  
{  
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();  
    // Make a big red pen.  
    Pen p= new Pen(Color.Red, 7);  
    g.DrawLine(p, 1, 1, 100, 100);  
}
```

And the same goes for the other methods (MainForm_ResizeMove, etc.).